# Add default post UI to custom post types Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a few custom post types in wordpress by adding them manually in the functions.php file. Below is the code I use to generate one of the custom post types called "Parteneri".

```
/**
* Create Parteneri post type
*/
function register_parteneri_post_type(){
  $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x('Parteneri', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain'),
    'singular_name'         => _x('Partener', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain'),
    'menu_name'             => _x('Parteneri', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain'),
    'name_admin_bar'        => _x('Partener', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain'),
    'add_new'               => __('Add New', 'textdomain'),
    'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Partener', 'textdomain'),
    'new_item'              => __('New Partener', 'textdomain'),
    'edit_item'             => __('Edit Partener', 'textdomain' ),
    'view_item'             => __('View Partener', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'             => __('All Parteneri', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'          => __('Search Parteneri', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Parteneri:', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'             => __('No parteneri found.', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No parteneri found in Trash.', 'textdomain' ),
    'featured_image'        => _x('Partener Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => _x('Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => _x('Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => _x('Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
    'archives'              => _x('Partener archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => _x('Insert into parteneri', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x('Uploaded to this parteneri', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => _x('Filter parteneri list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => _x('Parteneri list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    'items_list'            => _x('Parteneri list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    $args = array(
      'labels'              => $labels,
      'public'              => true,
      'publicly_queryable'  => true,
      'show_ui'             => true,
      'show_in_menu'        => true,
      'query_var'           => true,
      'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'parteneri'),
      'capability_type'     => 'post',
      'has_archive'         => true,
      'hierarchical'        => false,
      'menu_position'       => null,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments')
    );

    register_post_type('parteneri', $args);
}
```

The problem I am currently encountering is that the Visual text editor that gets added to this custom post type does not have the same options available for a normal WordPress 'post' type. For example, I would like to change the color of the text directly from the visual editor. Attached you have screenshots on how it looks on the custom post type vs a normal post.

This is how it looks on the custom post type.
[image]

This is how it looks on the post editor.
[image]

This is another example from another website of the settings I am looking for.
[image]

How am I able to get the UI with all the settings options of a normal 'post' type to a custom post type created in the functions.php? I assume I might be missing an option in the $args array, but I am not sure which one.

Comment: What happens when you press the [kitchen sink button](https://clarkwp.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/whats-on-the-wordpress-kitchen-sink/)?

Comment: The kitchen sink button does exactly what it is supposed to do, reveal the menu to change the color of the text! It was obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to get Gutenberg showing on your Custom Post Type is to add this to your Arguments' array:

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).